# TexMaker - Index is not Automatically Generating

Tags: texmaker, indexing, makeindex

When I run PdfLatex in TexMaker, a .idx file is generated, but not an .idn file. Can I configure TexMaker to generate the .idn file?

I use Ubuntu and can manually generate the .idn file by running makeindex on the .idx file in the terminal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex
\begin{document}

This is a test\index{test}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Last time I checked there is a command in texmaker to run make index, see the tools menu. Like wuth bibtex, texmaker does not run these automatically

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFkX9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can roll your own Quick Build like this

[image]